# How to create a unique sequential id for a record with specific recordtype

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, administration

I want to create a unique id for records with a specific record type of a custom object.

- The goal is to use something like {00000}-XX ex 00023-kl,00024-kl. where the number could be a 5 digit with 2 letters at the end and the numbers being sequential,

also there would be a need to change the alphabets periodically (3 years) which then should start the count from 0.

whats the best way to tackle this using flow (Preferably ),
autonumber would have worked except I only want this for a specific record type

Tried creating a flow that queries existing  records and gets the last generated id and increments it by 1, but when uploading records using data loader all the records in that batch had the same id due to flows using batches

Comment: IMHO, this has to be done in apex and will require a mutex solution to prevent two transactions creating records at the same time smashing each others numbering

Comment: @cropredy I was writing an answer to that effect. But you can use InvocableMethod to minimize the Apex you need.

Comment: @sfdcfox - I'm curious -- the invocable will be bulkified but you could have multiple Txns concurrently running (e.g. two DataLoaders running at the same time from different users)

Comment: Formula field that derives this id from the autonumber-ed Name field.

Comment: @cropredy Yeah, a FOR UPDATE on a mutex object should fix that problem. Each bulk flow thing happens separately--two users with data loader running should guarantee unique values.

Comment: identigral's solution is nice if you don't care about gaps in the numbering scheme (and, as formula) means searching on it is inefficient

Comment: @cropredy Trivia: formula fields can be indexed: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/221185/can-a-formula-field-be-indexed .

Comment: @identigral this would have worked but because I only need it for certain record types as cropredy mentioned would cause gaps in the numbering which we wanna avoid

Comment: @Sam ...with a little more elbow grease: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/267422/how-to-create-a-customised-auto-number-functionality-through-apex